# CABasicAnimation stop animation on completion - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation, uiviewanimation, cabasicanimation

I have an iOS app which is using a `CABasicAnimation` on repeat:

```
    CABasicAnimation *fadeAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    fadeAnim.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
    fadeAnim.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.2];
    fadeAnim.duration = 1.0;
    fadeAnim.autoreverses = YES;
    fadeAnim.repeatCount = INFINITY;
    [colourbutton.titleLabel.layer addAnimation:fadeAnim forKey:@"opacity"];
```

I have a button which when pressed is meant to stop the animation.

```
-(IBAction)stopAnim {
    [colourbutton.titleLabel.layer removeAllAnimations];
}
```

It works fine but one thing I am noticing is that is stops the animation suddenly, it doesn't let the animation finish. So how can I get it to finish the current animation and then stop. (Or in other words how can I get it to `removeAllAnimations....withAnimation`?).

On a side note, do I need to include `CoreAnimation` framework for this to work. So far the animation is running and I havn't imported the `CoreAnimation` framework.

Thanks, Dan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add another animation and after that remove the first one like this:

```
    CABasicAnimation *endAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    endAnimation.fromValue = @(((CALayer *)colourbutton.titleLabel.layer.presentationLayer).opacity);
    endAnimation.toValue = @(1);
    endAnimation.duration = 1.0;
    [colourbutton.titleLabel.layer addAnimation:endAnimation forKey:@"end"];
    [colourbutton.titleLabel.layer removeAnimationForKey:@"opacity"];
```

The key here is to use the presentation layer to get the current state. Don't forget to set the actual end state of the layer, because the animation will be removed on completion.

Comment: But I am using the "autoreverses" property. Adding another animation seems silly does it not?

Comment: @Supertecnoboff have you tried it? Second animation will be added on top of the reversing one. And reversing one will be removed immediately, so the user won't notice anything.

Comment: @Supertecnoboff so, have you tried the solution? I've used it a couple of times - works as expected.

Comment: Yep this works great thanks! (Sorry it took me so long to accept it).

Answer (score 0):

In NKorotov's answer, he uses the `presentationLayer` to find out where you are in the animation. That is the correct way to go.

You could go with this solution, although IMO you would also have to calculate the duration animation correctly (based on the duration of the original animation and on how far you are along the animation path currently).

If you find it "silly" to add a new animation, you could perhaps call `removeAllAnimations` using `dispatch_after` at the correct time.